# What does comparison operator in C return?

Tags: c, operators, output

```
int main()
{
    int x=35;
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n",x==35,x=50,x>35);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above main function the output comes out to be 0 50 0. Why is it so that the comparison operator is producing an output of 0 even when the value of `x` is equal to 35.

I am also bit confused in the output produced by `x>35` because when this is compiled the value of `x` has been updated to 50 than why is it so that it produces an output of 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Evaluation order of `printf` parameters is *unspecified* in the standard.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior

Answer (score 3):

x = 50 is assignment, and apparently, the parameters are evaluated in reversed order:

so x > 35 is evaluated to false (0) first, then x=50 as assignment, which evaluates to 50 as a side effect, then x == 35 which is false (0) again.

(Indeed, like other answer says, this execution order is not specified.

Comment: It is actually undefined behaviour. Reading and writing to the same variable with no intervening sequence points.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n",x==35,x=50,x>35);
```

It's unspecified whether `x==35` or `x=50` is evaluated first.

This is actually undefined behavior, you might see a different result on another machine.